# Prevent Web API project from launching in browser

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a solution in VS 2019, It has two ASP.NET Core projects, one is a web api project the other is just a web app that talks to the API project.

When I set it to run both projects. It launches 2 browser windows, one for the web api and the other for the web app.

Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from launching the Web API project in the browser (but have it running in the background)? I only communicate with the API via REST tools such as Insomnia, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Properties->launchSettings.json

You should see something like this:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "<YourProjectName>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

Just set the "launchBrowser" to "false" and you should be good!!